# Serializing large data in windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8

I am developing an app that will retrieve data from web. This data needs to be stored in the database of my local folder for future use. Presently I am saving the data in OnSuspending() function in App.xaml.cs. This event is called after some 8-10 sec. But when I quit the app and launch the app within some 5 sec, the data is not stored in database.

So I tried saving it saving in VisibilityChanged event and Activated event, since it is large amount of data, sometimes it is not saving. Eventhough I also get problem regarding VisibilityChanged event not being called when I go to background or When I launch the app before 8 sec.

So my question is When is the right time to store large amount of data?

Comment: The right time to store large amount of data is when you first retrieve it. After that update only the changed bits. It should always be possible to do that...

Comment: When I store large amount of data when I first retrieve it, it can take some 3-4 sec, but at the same time user can add a record to the same database in that 3-4 sec. I think it will create a problem.

Comment: Nope. you quite obviously are not knowing how to deal with databases. Proper programming will fix all those issues you think you have. tore the stuff when you get it, not at some funny point in the future.

Comment: Ok I will tore the stuff, Thanks man.